# Bad response in $.when().done()

Tags: jquery, ajax, promise

I tried to use the example of [jquery when](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/) where sending several ajax I have a problem because I can not understand why I get angry response. Generally, the response is bad when I try to send more than one ajax.

I`m doing it like this:

```
Workflow.prototype.ajaxWorkflowsPaymentProcessTransitionsAvailable = function (barcodes) {
        var workflow = this;
        return $.ajax({
            url: "api/v1.0/workflows/paymentProcess/transitions/available",
            type: "POST",
            data: {barcodes: barcodes},
            dataType: 'JSON'
        });
    };
Workflow.prototype.ajaxViewsDocuments = function (fd) {
        var workflow = this;
        
        return $.ajax({
            url: "api/v1.0/views/documents",
            type: "POST",
            data: fd,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            dataType: 'JSON'
        });
    };

$.when(workflow.ajaxViewsDocuments(fd), workflow.ajaxWorkflowsPaymentProcessTransitionsAvailable(barcodes)).done(function(a1, a2){
            console.log(a1, a2);
        });
```

and I`v got this in console.log:

[image]

but server response this:

[image]
[image]

how can I get the same response which returns the server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery ajax returns three results.  So, when you use two ajax calls with `$.when()`, each argument passed to the `$.when()` callback is passed two arrays, where each array has the three arguments for an ajax call in it.

So, in your code change this:

```
console.log(a1, a2);
```

to this:

```
console.log(a1[0], a2[0]);
```

The three typical arguments you get back from a jQuery ajax call are passed in `a1[0]`, `a1[1]`, `a2[2]`.  The returned data argument is in the `[0]` element of each array.  You can see examples in the doc [here](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/).

---

You could create your own wrapper around `$.ajax()` that would take it's three result values and trim them down to one result value and then `$.when()` won't put them into an array.

```
// wrapper function to make return result from $.ajax() be one single argument
$.ajax2 = function() {
    return $.ajax.apply($, arguments).then(function(result) {
        // return only single result, not all three typical arguments
        // so $.when() won't put the args in an array
        return result;
    });
};
```

Then, you would use it like this (note the change from `$.ajax()` to `$.ajax2()`):

```
Workflow.prototype.ajaxWorkflowsPaymentProcessTransitionsAvailable = function (barcodes) {
    var workflow = this;
    return $.ajax2({
        url: "api/v1.0/workflows/paymentProcess/transitions/available",
        type: "POST",
        data: {barcodes: barcodes},
        dataType: 'JSON'
    });
};
Workflow.prototype.ajaxViewsDocuments = function (fd) {
    var workflow = this;

    return $.ajax2({
        url: "api/v1.0/views/documents",
        type: "POST",
        data: fd,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        dataType: 'JSON'
    });
};

$.when(workflow.ajaxViewsDocuments(fd), workflow.ajaxWorkflowsPaymentProcessTransitionsAvailable(barcodes)).done(function (a1, a2) {
    console.log(a1, a2);
});
```

I tested the concept with jQuery 1.x, 2.x and 3.x here: https://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/2mcLsw3f/

Comment: I know I can get it by what you propose but I dont want to get it by this way. I want get in done response the same like from server with out using this array. I dont want use a1[0] etc.

Comment: @rad11 - That's how jQuery Ajax works with `$.when()`.  I agree it's kind of a broken design (especially given how std ES6 promises work), but you can't change it.

Comment: @rad11 - FYI, you could make your own wrapper for `$.ajax()` that would work around this if you called your wrapper instead.

Comment: How that wrapper could look?

Comment: @rad11 - I added an implementation of the wrapper to my answer.